# Ethna Controller _trigger_WWW(/lib/Ethna/class/Ethna_Controller.php:875): undefined action [xxx_index] [ERROR CODE(32)]

Tags: php

I had get an error when try creat new action for ethna framework.
I copy old action to new folder and rename all. (acction, template, UrlHandler) and it work in local (window, php 5.2).
But when i comit this source to linux server (php5.3). it not work.
i check log and get this error:
Ethna_Controller._trigger_WWW(/lib/Ethna/class/Ethna_Controller.php:875): undefined action [xxx_index] [ERROR CODE(32)]

i tried to echo action var in Ethna_Controller.php, line 918 ($action_obj =& $this->_getAction($action_name);), where alert this error, but nothing to show, i got empy page

So any worked with this framework, please help me!
Thank

Comment: Linux is case-sensitive, while windows is case-insensitive, check letters case.

Comment: thank, this is my problem, one folder is uppercase

Answer (score 0):

*Moving comment to answer to be accepted*

Since you are telling that on your Windows server everything is working and moving to Linux it stops working, than it must be case-sensitiveness. Windows is case-insensitive (means `Folder/MyClass` and `folder/myClass` is equal and will not throw any error. Linux is case-sensitive (means `Folder/MyClass` and `folder/myClass` are not equal and path will be not found leading to error). Check if all your paths are in correct case.